# Adding content to ms word, Include macro

Tags: java, vba, ms-word

I have a JSP file to flush all data from database into a MS-Word document by setting the `content-type` keyword.

I need to add header and footer to the same document. I couldn't find a direct way from JSP without using APIs like POI. So I created a macro which works locally.

How do I add this to a dynamically generated Word file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with POI and Excel.

The solution is to manually create a template .doc file, with the macro present. Then in your code, load that document, amend it with your data, and save it. The macro will be preserved from the template document.

Comment: Thanks for your tip.. But U mean to use POI to do this?? Currently as I said it is a JSP page with 'contenttype set as ms word'.. Is it possible to open and append data to the existing template doc without POI stuff?? If so I'm not sure how (Though I have my templates ready :)).. Do help me on this..! Thanks

Comment: I think the best way is to use POI to do anything relating to Microsoft formats.

Comment: ok then.. But the work time involving to resolve this thing isn't so satisfactory.. Anyway thanks man..!! I will have a look into this..

Answer (score 0):

I'd use POI or docx4j to create a docx file on the server, and add the header/footer as part of that process.